# Close recent windows of an application

Tags: applications, firefox, macos, alfred

I'm using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) in order to control multiple Firefox sessions at the same time.

In this context, the OS handles each Firefox window as a different application.

I want to build a workflow that'll allow me to close all the recent windows of Firefox (leaving the "oldest" one working), but I couldn't find any way to sort them by their opening date.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12579934/3103891) I was able to print the IDs and the names of all the processes that currently run.

I then ran a few tests and these are my insights:

1. The processes are sorted by most recent.
2. The Firefox processes that Selenium opens are named "firefox-bin", as opposed to the usual "firefox" process/es.
3. Hence the IDs' order matches the names' order, so it allows to cross between the lists and identify the windows that Selenium has opened.

The code I used is:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the name of every process whose background only is false
set _name to result
tell application "System Events" to get the id of every process whose background only is false
set _id to result

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
do shell script ({"echo", _name & " " & _id, "| tr ' ' '\\n'", "| sort -n"} as string)`
```

It's not optimal, but I just needed to get the right IDs, so this test was enough for me to move on.

Comment: Good job!  That’s some nice detective work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access window menu of Firefox, the oldest window at top of the list

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer.  If it's an answer can you expand on *how* this solves the OP's question?

Comment: As I've mentioned, because I open the Firefox windows through Selenium, each of them shows as a separate application

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with *Selenium*, but I wonder if you could use an AppleScript (which *Alfred* can happily make use of) to get the window **id**'s of each *Firefox* window.  Window **id**’s are normally assigned incrementally, so a recent window will have an **id** of greater numeric value than those that came before it.

```
    tell application "Firefox" to get every window
```

should return a list of all windows referenced by their id numbers, e.g.

```
    {window id 59 of application "Firefox", window id 2408 of application "Firefox", window id 61 of application "Firefox", window id 60 of application "Firefox"}
```

Of course, I wonder how running multiple, separate instances of *Firefox* will affect this, as I can't predict whether AppleScript will send the `get windows` command to all *Firefox* instances or just one (and, if so, which one?).

If that line works as I want it to, then you can pick out the one with the smallest **id** and close the others.  Here's one way to do that:

```
    tell application "Firefox" to get the id of every window

    set W to result

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    do shell script ({"echo", W, "| tr ' ' '\\n'", "| sort -n"} as string)
        --> Outputs lines sorted from smallest to greatest value

    set W to first paragraph of result

    tell application "Firefox" to close (windows whose id > W)
```

Comment: +1 for the effort you put into this, although it prints only 1 Firefox window ID, which is the main one's

Comment: I feared that might be a possible result, given what you said about *Selenium* creating multiple instances.  Sorry about that.  Thanks for +1, though.